# Calls to Geocode were fine, but are now sometimes very slow

Tags: php, google-api, geocoding, google-geocoder

I've been using a Google Geocode call for several months without problem. 
Until a few days ago: now it sometimes it takes over 60 seconds to respond - 
 the status is "OK" and the fields I need are present in the return area.

It's fine most of the time but I get occasional problems.
I have re-created the problem by making 3 or 4 calls in quick succession: 
the last call takes over 60 seconds.

I have confirmed:

- That the delay occurs at the `curl_exec($ch)` statement. (I did this by running the code up to, but excluding this statement, there were no problems. As soon as I include `curl_exec($ch)` then, after a few calls, it takes over 60 seconds).
- I am nowhere near the limit of 2,500 requests per day.
- The status field is "OK" and not "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT".
- I am using PHP (version: 5.2.17).

The code is below:

```
      function geocode($postcode){
       $locality = '';
       $administrative_area_level_2 = '';
       $administrative_area_level_1 = '';
       $postal_town = '';
       $formatted_address = '';
       $longitude = 0 ;
       $latitude = 0 ;

   $postcode1 = str_replace(' ','_',$postcode) . ',UK'; 
   $string = str_replace (" ", "+", urlencode($string));


   $details_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$postcode1."&sensor=false"; 



   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $details_url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   $temp = curl_exec($ch) ;
   $response = json_decode($temp, true);

   $geo_error = $response['status'];

   if ( $geo_error == 'OK' ) {              // oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
   $names = array();
   $names[0] =  $response['results'][0]['address_components'][0][long_name] ;
   $names[1] =  $response['results'][0]['address_components'][1][long_name] ;
   $names[2] =  $response['results'][0]['address_components'][2][long_name] ;
   $names[3] =  $response['results'][0]['address_components'][3][long_name] ;
   $names[4] =  $response['results'][0]['address_components'][4][long_name] ;
   $types = array();
   $types[0] =  $response['results'][0]['address_components'][0][types][0] ;
   $types[1] =  $response['results'][0]['address_components'][1][types][0] ;
   $types[2] =  $response['results'][0]['address_components'][2][types][0] ;
   $types[3] =  $response['results'][0]['address_components'][3][types][0] ;
   $types[4] =  $response['results'][0]['address_components'][4][types][0] ; 

   for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {
      switch ($types[$i]) {
       case 'locality':
          $locality = $names[$i];
          break;
       case 'administrative_area_level_2':
          $administrative_area_level_2 = $names[$i];
          break;
       case 'administrative_area_level_1':
          $administrative_area_level_1 = $names[$i];
          break;
       case 'postal_town':
          $postal_town = $names[$i];
          break;
       default:
          break;
      } // end of switch  
   } // end of for
   $formatted_address = $response['results'][0]['formatted_address'] ;

   $geometry = $response['results'][0]['geometry'];
   $longitude = $geometry['location']['lng'];
   $latitude = $geometry['location']['lat'];

   $address_components = $response['results'][0]['address_components'];

   $array = array(
     'latitude' => $geometry['location']['lat'],
     'longitude' => $geometry['location']['lng'],
     'location_type' => $geometry['location_type'],
   );

   } else {       // ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
   // geo did not work so log error and report

   } // end if     oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
return array($longitude,$latitude,$locality,$administrative_area_level_2,
   $administrative_area_level_1,$postal_town,$formatted_address,$geo_error);
```

I'd be very grateful for any help.

Thanks
Brian.

Comment: Any chance you're being rate-limited? There could be minute-wise quotas as well as daily quotas. These could be delayed, not denied.

Comment: Are you stuck with the google api?  Do they offer something you can't get elsewhere?  Is it their lat/lon precision that you're looking for, or address standardization, or address parsing?  Can you give a little more information, about what you are inputting and what you are expecting?